# Как вытащить из словаря всё его элементы и их значения?

Tags: python

Суть такая, у меня есть словарь под названием `ad_features` в котором может быть любое количество элементов с их значениями, задача такая: вытащить из словаря всё его элементы и их значение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: https://pythonru.com/osnovy/python-dict

Comment: заголовок противоречит остальному тексту вопроса. поправьте, пожалуйста, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ad_features = {1:2, 2:3,3:4}
keys = ad_features.keys()
for i in keys:
    print(i, ad_features.get(i))
```

Думаю, вам это поможет

Answer (score 2):

`ad_features.items()` перебирает пары ключ/значение в словаре:

```
ad_features = { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2' }

for k, v in ad_features.items():
    print(f'key is {k}, value is {v}')
```

> ```
> key is key1, value is value1
> key is key2, value is value2
> ```